# Silent speech recognition method or system with highest accuracy?

Tags: brain-computer-interface, electrophysiology

Is there any other silent speech recognition method (EEG/ECoG/Intracortical etc), with accuracy as good as the Audeo device developed by [Michael Callahan](https://about.me/michaelcallahan) and team - see the demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Gl1DnMVco), which is based on non-invasive EMG readings at larynx ? By silent recognition, I mean any method which does not require actual phonation, although most of the such methods will come under electrophysiology.

Comment: Have you explored the lip-reading speech recognition solutions?